# Windows 10 not booting, black screen and blinking cursor

Tags: boot, windows-10

My windows 10 no longer boots.

It only shows this (black screen, blinking console cursor).

I think the problem started yesterday when, after shutdown the windows would show shutting down, the PC turns off and then turns itself on. I disabled the wake up on LAN stuff but it was still turning on after shut down. To keep it shutdown I had to use the power button of my PC.

Now, it doesn't boot, never reaches the blue windows 10 logo. I found no way to get to safe mode (I have MSI b57a-g43 motherboard and an Intel 300 SSD as my boot drive).

Tried resetting CMOS, moving the display from the dedicated to the integrated GPU.

Any ideas how I could at least know what is wrong?

Last thing I did was installing the latest windows updates, trying to fix the self turn-on problem. It successfully booted after the updates so I turned it off. Later when I checked I had this black screen problem.

Thanks...

Other notes:

1. If I insert a Windows 7 DVD (I have no windows 10 disk) it seems to boot fine until the installation screen.

Comment: Fixed it by re-installing Windows.

Comment: This is a non-reproducible question that was fixed by reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Happened to me too.....you'll need to download windows 10 onto a jump drive (using another computer of course) and reformat our drive.  I'm assuming you can see the drive from BIOS.  Once your reformat screen appears you'll need to delete all partitions!  Follow instructions.  Once re-formated do not use auto configure but select so you can turn off all the built in spyware that comes with windows 10.